# How do BAAS solutions both allow custom code and keep things secure?

Tags: security, server-side, parse-platform, stackmob

Baas, backend-as-a-service, solutions like [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) and [StackMob](http://www.stackmob.com) allow application developers to add and use custom code to run server-side business logic. I'm interested in learning how you could add functions to the app server without disruptions to other applications and keep malicious code from accessing the system or data they shouldn't.

I've searched for any posts or disclosures of how Parse or StackMob might have built up their architectures and have come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how [Kii Cloud](http://www.kii.com) provides [custom server side code](http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/serverextension/) that you can add to the backend. It basically runs in a sandbox with some access to the server side API (but it's well defined, the user can only access what they are intended to access). An there are also resource limitations such as time constraints (a piece of server code can take do processing forever).

This is not exactly the internals of Kii but I think server side code in most MBaaS providers reflects on what's the correct way to add server side logic on a running system without disrupting the system.
Please head to [community.kii.com](http://community.kii.com) if you want to discuss internals with the engineers (we're happy to chat with you).